# How to import vendored css from gem with cssbundling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, cssbundling-rails

Is it possible to import vendored css from gem with cssbundling ? If yes, how ?

For example :

Gemfile `gem 'semantic-ui-sass'`

application.scss `@import "semantic-ui/collections/menu";`

Gives me `Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.` with sass compiler

Comment: What you do is actually the recommended install: https://github.com/doabit/semantic-ui-sass . Have you done a `bundle install` after adding the gem to your gemfile ? Do a `bundle list` in console and check `semantic-ui-sass` is indeed there.

Comment: Yes the gem is well installed. I move from sprocket (with Rails 6) to css-bundling (with Rails 7)

Comment: Does it work if you keep the Sprockets gem in your Gemfile ?

Comment: Sprockets is already present

Comment: Last think I am thinking of if you don't have the 'sassc' gem and your environment file using "scss" : `config.assets.css_compressor = :scss`. Sprockets may not be finding the stylesheet as it would look for .css sinstead of .scss in case SCSS is not enabled.

Comment: Help! I'm hitting the same issue here. Trying to import active_admin sass files and it's not working with rails 7.